# How do I add Click Tags to an HTML document?

Tags: html, flash, dreamweaver, ads, clicktag

Forgive me if this is a stupid question - I'm pretty new to coding. How can I add a Clicktag to a Dreamweaver HTML document? I have some Flash ads built out with lots of clicktags (for AOL, Google, etc.), but I need to add these clicktags to a Dreamweaver document. Apparently I can't just copy and paste because the clicktags in Flash are written in ActionScript. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I dont entirely get what you mean by click tags

Comment: Clicktags are used for Flash ads: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clicktag

Comment: So you want to have a simple link from one document to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire point of click tags is the URL **not** being in flash and rather the flash simply accepting an external parameter (called `clickTAG`) and using that parameter as the click URL, making that URL editable outside of the flash.

So either the URL is not part of the actionscript (the flash), *or it's not a click tag*. If it is a click tag then you need to learn how to embed flash in HTML while passing parameters to it, because that's how click tags work. The flash itself does not need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTag = "https://www.google.com";
</script>
```

and on your link or button div

```
onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)"
```

AdOps employees using Doubleclick Campaign Manager input the correct URL. Google.com i sjust a place holder.